# SLURM new resources management

Tags: resources, slurm

I'm a SLURM newby.
I have jobs that require virtual resources allocation.
In LSF there is a file call lsb.resources that help us to set max values for each resources created.
Then, during the job submission, one tell to the scheduler how many resources the job uses.
I'm wondering whether it's possible to set up a similar behavior with SLURM.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I got it.
It calls license in slurm and it's just one line to add in slurm.conf.